# Command Blocks Mob Land Filler

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I made a TNT cannon in superflat and now there is obviously a large hole in the world. I would like a system that will fill in the area, but I don't know how to use command blocks very well.

I don't want to just to use a simple /fill command, rather, I think it would be cool to have a mob, say a horse, walk around in the hole and where ever it goes the land around him is filled in. I don't know if it's possible, but it would definetely be very fun to watch. He would also need to have invulnerability, too so TNT does not kill him. Is there a command to do this?

Comment: But, obviously, if nobody feels like doing it, i would like to know the /fill command for this. Please use relative coordinates if possible to simplify things:)

Comment: You'll get a better reception when you have a problem you're trying to solve, rather than asking us to make it for you.  Pick a solution, and try to implement it.  If you get stuck, tell us where you're stuck.  Just going, "I have this cool idea, tell me how do it!" doesn't work very well.

Comment: Also, please don't vandalize your question.  If you no longer want this question, you have a delete button available to you.

Answer (score 1):

To create it with a custom name and invincibility:

```
summon Chicken ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"Landfiller",Invulberable:1b}
```

To constantly fill in the land (put this one on a clock):

```
execute @e[name=Landfiller,type=Chicken] ~ ~ ~ fill ~-1 1 ~-1 ~1 ~-1 ~1 minecraft:sandstone
```

Things to change:

- You can modify the block you want to fill in with (change the `minecraft:sandstone` part)
- You can experiment with different relative coordinates to fill in different amounts of land as the chicken walks (right now it's set to a 3x3 area centered on the chicken)
- You can change which mob you use (Chicken AI is stupid, might be better off using something else)

[Here is the Minecraft Wiki's Commands page.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands)

Also check out some YouTube channels for some more info about commands and command blocks.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/summon chicken ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"\"Landfiller\""}`, `/execute at @e[name=Landfiller,type=chicken] run fill ~-1 1 ~-1 ~1 ~-1 ~1 minecraft:sandstone`